# Why does creating training sets with replacement lead to better performance?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, ensemble-learning, bagging

Pasting generally suffers from lower performance than bagging, because it training sets without replacement. Why does creating training sets with replacement lead to better performance?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Powerpoint](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/slides/Chapter12.pptx) from The University of Waikato:

> The idealized version of bagging improves performance because it eliminates the variance component of the error.

In this case, they are assuming `Total Error` = `Bias` + `Variance`.